# "Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I have imported AppDelegate.h in the file.. Here's the code in the file. This is in main.m.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder  <NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: Check the spelling of your file AppDelegate.m, and the spelling used in your code line UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: Please add AppDelegate.h

Comment: @KIDdAe there you go sir

Comment: Did you have a `AppDelegate` class ?

Comment: @KudoCC I'm following this tutorial exactly, if it helps you understand where I am coming from. http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: also, I have an AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m right now. As you guys can see, I'm new and I'm just working my way through stuff slowly, trying to get a little push or a shove when I get stuck in the mud

Comment: I notice that there is a [starter project for this tutorial](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/downloads/ByteClub_Starter.zip) in the link. Well, you should have a `AppDelegate` class which inherits from `UIResponder` and conform To `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Comment: @KudoCC Can you explain to me what the difference between having an AppDelegate.m and .h and having an AppDelegate class is? I thought they were synonymous

Comment: Your AppDelegate.h have wrong @interface name.."UIViewController ()" it should be "AppDelegate"

Comment: I changed some stuff around, now the error is no known class method for selector "class".

Comment: Shouldn't AppDelegate implement UIApplicationDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppDelegate` class declaration does not match a correct `AppDelegate` interface.

Replace this line :

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder  <NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>
```

with this line :

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Then, you'll have to implement methods declared in `UIApplicationDelegate`

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

When you create a project using Xcode, all this would be generated.